# Constructing an increasing function on a set A that is continuous only at the irrational points in A.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> **Exercise 6.2**
>
> Show that there is a strictly increasing function on $[0,1]$ that is continuous only at the irrational numbers in $[0,1]$ .
>
> **Proof** Let $C=[0,1] \cap \mathbf{Q}$ and let $\left\{q_{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of $C .$ Define the function $f$ on [0,1] by setting
> $$
> f(x)=\sum_{\left\{n \mid q_{n} \leq x\right\}} \frac{1}{n^{2}} \text { for all } 0 \leq x \leq 1
> $$
> since a $p$ -series converges for all $p>1, \ f$ is well-defined. Observe that if $0 \leq x<y \leq 1,$ then
> $$
> f(y)-f(x)=\sum_{\left\{n \mid q_{n} \leq y\right\}} \frac{1}{n^{2}}-\sum_{\left\{n \mid q_{n} \leq x\right\}} \frac{1}{n^{2}}=\sum_{\left\{n \mid x<q_{n} \leq y\right\}} \frac{1}{n^{2}}>0
> $$
> which implies that $f(y)>f(x)$. Hence $f$ is strictly increasing, as desired.

The question is the one above and what follows is my attempt. I now need to show that this function is continuous only at the irrational numbers, but I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: Can you show it's discontinuous at the rationals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that there is a slight problem with your question as stated :
you must exclude $0$ to avoid ugly things like $\frac{1}{0^2}$.

Let $r$ be a rational number in $(0,1]$. There is an index
$i_0$ such that $r=q_{i_0}$

Let $r_m=r-\frac{1}{m}$. We have $r_m\in[0,1]$ for all large enough
  $m$, and then one has

$$
 f(r)-f(r_m)=\sum_{ r_m <q_n  \leq r } \frac{1}{n^2}
 \geq \sum_{ n=i_0 } \frac{1}{n^2} =\frac{1}{i_0^2}
 $$

In particular, the sequence $(f(r_m))$ cannot  converge to $f(r)$.
 So $f$ is discontinuous (in fact, it is left-discontinuous) at $r$.